# Set Unique Constraint only under the direct parents (Django MPTT)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unique-constraint, django-mptt

I created **"Category" model** with **Django MPTT**:

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        related_name="children"
    )
```

But, with this **"Category" model**, I could add the duplicated data **"3F"** and **"4F"** under **"Building B"(Direct Parent)** as shown below:

- **USA**

  - **New York**

    - **Building A**

      - **3F**
      - **4F**
    - **Building B**

      - **3F** // Here
      - **3F** // Here
      - **4F** // Here
      - **4F** // Here

So I added **"unique=True"** to **"name" field** in **"Category" model**:

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):                 // Here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        related_name="children"
    )
```

But with this **"Category"** model, I couldn't add the data **"3F"** and **"4F"** under **"Building B"** anymore because **"3F"** and **"4F"** already exist under **"Building A"** in **"Category"**. I found adding **"unique=True"** to **"name" field** in **"Category" model** sets **Unique Constraint** in **whole "Category" model** about **"name" field**. So if there are **the same "name" values such as **"F3"** and **"F4"** anywhere in "Category"**, we cannot add **the same "name" values such as **"F3"** and **"F4"** anywhere in "Category"**. In short, if **"3F"** and **"4F"** already exist anywhere in **"Category"**, we cannot add **"3F"** and **"4F"** anywhere in **"Category"**:

- **USA**

  - **New York**

    - **Building A**

      - **3F** // Because already exists
      - **4F** // Because already exists
    - **Building B**

      - **3F** // So cannot add
      - **3F** // So cannot add
      - **4F** // So cannot add
      - **4F** // So cannot add

This is my desired result not allowing duplicated data **only under the direct parents**:

- **USA**

  - **New York**

    - **Building A**

      - **3F** // Even though already exists
      - **4F** // Even though already exists
    - **Building B**

      - **3F** // 〇 But allowed to add
      - **3F** // ✖ Not allowed to add
      - **4F** // 〇 But allowed to add
      - **4F** // ✖ Not allowed to add

Are there any ways to set **Unique Constraint only under the direct parents**?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"unique=True"** from **"name" field**:

```py
name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # "unique=True" is removed
```

Then, add this code below to **"Category" model** :

```py
class Meta:
    unique_together = [['name', 'parent']]
```

This is the full code:

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel): # "unique=True" is removed
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        related_name="children"
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['name', 'parent']]
```

This code above realizes **what you desire**:

- **USA**

  - **New York**

    - **Building A**

      - **3F** // Even though already exists
      - **4F** // Even though already exists
    - **Building B**

      - **3F** // 〇 But allowed to add
      - **3F** // ✖ Not allowed to add
      - **4F** // 〇 But allowed to add
      - **4F** // ✖ Not allowed to add

But only **the top level(level 1)** still doesn't have **Unique Constraint** so **the top level(level 1)** still can have duplicated data as shown below:

- **USA**

  - **New York**

    - **Building A**

      - **3F**
      - **4F**
    - **Building B**

      - **3F**
      - **4F**
- **USA** // 〇 Allowed to add
- **USA** // 〇 Allowed to add.

Actually, I tried some solutions to add **Unique Constraint** to **the top level(level 1)** but I couldn't so I recommend not to use **the top level(level 1)** to store the proper data which you actually use for your app. So instead, to **the top level(level 1)**, just add **"Root"**, **"Top"** or whatever shows **"This is the top level(level 1)"** as shown below:

- **Root** // Here

  - **USA**

    - **New York**

      - **Building A**

        - **3F**
        - **4F**
      - **Building B**

        - **3F**
        - **4F**